# Is there a way to modify a field in a table line by line based upon the contents of each individual field (DB2 or other)?

Tags: sql, database, powershell, db2

I have a DB2 table that has a field containing a specific value (SOCIAL SECURITY numbers). I need to modify each row's field value depending upon the contents of the field. I grab the original field's value and based upon it, I create a new value. Basically I'm using the the original value as the seed to create a new value so I need to know each value and update the field based up on it... I'm sorry for being so vague, I'm still trying to understand all of this.

This SQL changed all of the values to a single value which is wrong
Update Table set SSN = '123-45-6789'

I need to:

1. Get value of the field
2. Using the current value as a seed, mask it using a simple formula

619-46-0988--->427-95-1143
424-09-8912--->699-01-4628
619-46-0988--->427-95-1143

### Notice that 619-46-0988 is changed consistently as the original value was the same

Thanks so much,

Barbara

Comment: Please _edit the question_ and explain _what and why_ you'd like to do this. There might be better options, such as using DB2's [data mask](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createmask.html), but this depends on what you really are after.

Comment: You may implement your own algorithm which must translate data consistently and preserve uniqueness. This may be some distinct shuffling algorithm for every digit like adding a constant and returning the reminder of division by 10 or constant one-to-one digit mapping without repetition. It's relatively easy to implement such an SQL scalar function.

Comment: What `update` set the values to the same value?  I don't see any `update`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest masking function example.
Unique and consistent result on unique set of SSNs with constant 2-nd parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SSN_MASK(P_SSN VARCHAR(11), P_MASK VARCHAR(9)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(11)
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC 
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
RETURN
CASE
   WHEN 
         REGEXP_LIKE(P_SSN,  '^[\d]{3}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{4}$')
     AND REGEXP_LIKE(P_MASK, '^[\d]{9}$')
   THEN
        MOD(INT(SUBSTR(P_SSN,  1, 1)) + INT(SUBSTR(P_MASK, 1, 1)), 10)
     || MOD(INT(SUBSTR(P_SSN,  2, 1)) + INT(SUBSTR(P_MASK, 2, 1)), 10)
     || MOD(INT(SUBSTR(P_SSN,  3, 1)) + INT(SUBSTR(P_MASK, 3, 1)), 10)
     || '-'
     || MOD(INT(SUBSTR(P_SSN,  5, 1)) + INT(SUBSTR(P_MASK, 4, 1)), 10)
     || MOD(INT(SUBSTR(P_SSN,  6, 1)) + INT(SUBSTR(P_MASK, 5, 1)), 10)
     || '-'
     || MOD(INT(SUBSTR(P_SSN,  8, 1)) + INT(SUBSTR(P_MASK, 6, 1)), 10)
     || MOD(INT(SUBSTR(P_SSN,  9, 1)) + INT(SUBSTR(P_MASK, 7, 1)), 10)
     || MOD(INT(SUBSTR(P_SSN, 10, 1)) + INT(SUBSTR(P_MASK, 8, 1)), 10)
     || MOD(INT(SUBSTR(P_SSN, 11, 1)) + INT(SUBSTR(P_MASK, 9, 1)), 10)
END
;
    
SELECT V, SSN_MASK(V, '123456789') V_MASKED 
FROM 
(
VALUES 
  '619-46-0988'
, '424-09-8912'
, '619-46-0988'
, 'ABC'
) T(V);
    
The result is: 
        
|V          |V_MASKED   |
|-----------|-----------|
|619-46-0988|732-81-6667|
|424-09-8912|547-44-4691|
|619-46-0988|732-81-6667|
|ABC        |NULL       |
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean, you could use the SSN as a seed to System.Random, and that will always return a predictable next value. As long as the RNG function doesn't change it's consistent.

You could do this:

```bsh
PS C:\> $rng = [System.Random]::new([int]'619-46-0988'.Replace('-',''))
PS C:\> $rng.Next(1e9).ToString('000-00-0000')
010-05-3964
```

Or this:

```bsh
PS C:\> (Get-Random -Maximum 1e9 -SetSeed ([int]'619-46-0988'.Replace('-',''))).ToString('000-00-0000')
660-94-7295
```

Should you do it this way? *Absolutely not.* It's not secure and it's trivial to generate the entire used key space and create a rainbow table. Also, it doesn't generate values that fit [the SSN allowed ranges](https://www.ssa.gov/employer/stateweb.htm) (such as not beginning with 000) so they may not be appropriate depending on your application.

A *more* right way to do this would be to treat the SSN like a password, probably with something like bcrypt/scrypt or PBKDF2 or some other cryptographic hashing function, and then use the hash to more directly generate a 9 digit number that "becomes" the new SSN (e.g., consume the least significant bytes to create a 9 digit integer).

However, in any circumstance I could imagine, the problem of "I need to obfuscate SSNs" my preferred solution would be "add a new column to the table or create a new table, then create surrogate keys associated with the person table key, and then purge SSNs to nulls and use the surrogates when I need to do that". Heck, your surrogate keys could just be the output of `(Get-Random -Maximum 1e9).ToString('000-00-0000')` which, as far as I know (but do your own research), uses `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator`. Even then, I wouldn't be keen to keep the surrogate keys around very long.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [UPDATE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001022.html) statement. You haven't specified how the new value is computed, but it is a common scenario to refer to the existing value: The new salary of each INDIVIDUAL employee should be based on the current existing salary.

The expression to compute the new value can be any [expression](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000736.html). Thus, you could look it up in another table or compute it in a function.

```
UPDATE myTable SET column = computedValue(column) WHERE howToIdentifyThoseToChange
```